# Ruby : How to do mapping IP address with the associated country

Tags: ruby, console-application

I want to Write a command line program that accepts an IP address, and returns the
country it's associate with.

For ex: 67.99.163.76 will output 'United States'.

Comment: https://github.com/weppos/whois

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [geocode gem](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/). It's very feature rich and have great support for rails and other rack-based frameworks. You can of cause also use it outside those frameworks both as an api and **from the console**. A small sample from the console:

```
geocode 67.99.163.76
```

> Latitude:         42.7684
>
> Longitude:        -78.8871
>
> Full address:     Buffalo, NY 14260, United States
>
> City:             Buffalo
>
> State/province:   New York
>
> Postal code:      14260
>
> Country:          United States
>
> Google map:       http://maps.google.com/maps?q=42.7684,-78.8871

You can do it using nothing but the standard library by querying freegeoip:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
ip = "67.99.163.76"
uri = URI.parse("http://freegeoip.net/json/#{ip}")
client = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
res = JSON.parse(client.get(uri.request_uri).body)
puts res["country_name"]
```

Comment: Thanks SSB. How can I write code for this without using geocode gem. Actually not want to implement this on any application. Just looking for one single ruby file solution.

Comment: @rajwar I've added an example which uses the standard library along with freegeoip.net

Comment: Thank you again SSB for your response. This is exact what I was looking.